# Which Google API(endpoint) returns SSO login activities

Tags: google-api

Tell me please, which Google API(endpoint) returns SSO login activities.
I have Google Workspace(G-Suite) and i need to know for which applications to login was used G-suite account

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include more details.  As it is written it is hard to understand what your issue is.  Knowing which API it is you are using and which method would help.  Also which language so adding your code would be of great help if you are having issues with authorization for instance

Comment: It’s hard to explain. Just would like to know when you use G-Suite as SAMl SSO if it’s possible to get applications list where this SSO was used?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need is to get the list of all the third party apps that your users have logged into using their Google accounts using the Google APIs. If so, what you can use is the [tokens.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/list) method, that way your will retrieve all the tokens a user has issued to 3rd party applications.

You can use the displayText and clientId values you get in the response to identify the app, and check the scopes to see the permissions of the app. Be aware that you can only retrieve the information from the last 6 months.